# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rd-component'

Tags: typescript, vite

I have write a public lib, today I changed the build tool from `microbundle` to `vite`. Now I am facing a problem that the `npm run build` show error when using this public lib:

```
> npm run build

> snap-web@0.1.0 build
> react-app-rewired build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rd-component' in '/Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/src/page/goods'
```

this is my public lib `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'node:path';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        dts({
            insertTypesEntry: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'rd-component',
            formats: ['es', 'umd'],
            fileName: 'rd-component',
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                    'styled-components': 'styled',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
    }
})
```

this is my `package.json` config:

```
{
    "name": "rd-component",
    "version": "0.1.45",
    "type": "module",
    "description": "Reddwarf public component lib",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js",
    "module": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": "./dist/rd-component.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/rd-component.umd.js"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.1.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
        "microbundle": "^0.15.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
        "antd": "^5.4.6",
        "vite-plugin-dts": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I am follow this tutoral to config the vite: https://dev.to/nicolaserny/create-a-react-component-library-with-vite-and-typescript-1ih9.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the filename configuration and make the public lib to generate es file:

from

```
fileName: 'rd-component',
```

to

```
fileName: (format) => `rd-component.${format}.js`
```